# ggvis: Confusing inheritance of properties from parent layer

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I have data frame like:

```
   x1  x2 y1 y2 labels       colors
1 1.0 1.1  1  2      A   blueviolet
2 1.3 1.4  1  2      A       azure1
3 1.0 1.1  3  4      B navajowhite3
4 1.3 1.4  3  4      B       grey46
```

which contains the positions for rectangles and the labels. But when I try to add the text layer, I get a error message that x2 and y2 are unknown properties:

```
ggvis(data = df2, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, x2 = ~x2, y2 = ~y2) %>% 
   layer_rects(fill = ~colors) %>% 
   layer_text(x = ~ x1 - 1, y = ~y1 + 0.4, text := ~labels)

Error: Unknown properties: x2, y2.
Did you mean: x, y?
```

How can I tell to `ggvis` to remove x2 and y2 for the text layer?

I already tried the following, because the description of 'inherit' sounds promising:

```
ggvis(data = df2, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, x2 = ~x2, y2 = ~y2) %>% 
   layer_rects(fill = ~colors) %>% 
   layer_text(props(x = ~ x1 - 1, y = ~y1 + 0.4, inherit = FALSE), 
              text := ~labels)
```

but this fails with following error:

```
Error in new_prop.default(x, property, scale, offset, mult, env, event,  : 
  Unknown input to prop: list(property = "x", value = x1 - 1, scale = "x", offset = NULL, mult = NULL, event = "update", env = <environment>)list(property = "y", value = y1 + 0.4, scale = "y", offset = NULL, mult = NULL, event = "update", env = <environment>)
```

One  workaround is to specify all properties in all layers again, but I hope there is a better solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your guess is correct: you should use `inherit = FALSE`, but there's no need to wrap it into `props()` call.

```
ggvis(data = df2, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, x2 = ~x2, y2 = ~y2) %>% 
  layer_rects(fill = ~colors) %>% 
  layer_text(text := ~labels, inherit = F, x = ~x1 + 0.05, y = ~y1 + 0.5, fontSize := 40)
```

[image]

From a stylistic point of view, you should declare only "universal" mappings within `ggvis`, while keeping layer-specific ones within `layer_*`. In that case, the unwanted inheritance won't be a problem:

```
ggvis(data = df2) %>% 
  layer_rects(fill = ~colors, x = ~x1, y = ~y1, x2 = ~x2, y2 = ~y2) %>% 
  layer_text(text := ~labels, x = ~x1 + 0.05, y = ~y1 + 0.5, fontSize := 40)
```